# Undefined offset: 2 (laravel)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, controller

I am unable to store data from my form in the database.
I'm getting an 'InvalidArgumentException'-error in Carbon.php line 582:

My code:

```
public function store(){
  $rules = array(
    'news_date'       => 'required',
    'title'      => 'required'
  );
  $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);
  if ($validator->fails()) {
    return Redirect::to('NewsFeed/create')
      ->withErrors($validator)
      ->withInput();
  }$feed= new Feed;
        $feed->title = Input::get('title');
        $feed->description = Input::get('description');
        $feed->related_links = Input::get('links');
        $feed->input_user = Input::get('input_user');
        $date = Input::get('news_date');
        if($date!="")
        {
            $res_news_date=explode("-",$date);
            $news_date=$res_news_date[2]."-".$res_news_date[1]."-".$res_news_date[0];
            $feed->date = $news_date;
        }

        $expires = Input::get('news_end_date');
        if($expires!="")
        {
            $res_expiry_date=explode("-",$expires);
            $expire_date=$res_expiry_date[2]."-".$res_expiry_date[1]."-".$res_expiry_date[0];
            $feed->expires_on = $expire_date;
        }
        $feed->save();
}
```

my Feed modal:

```
class Feed extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'feed_news';
    use SoftDeletes;
    protected $softDelete = true;
    protected $dates = ['expires_on'];
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This error is because of the carbon can you please dd(Input::get('news_date'),Input::get('expires_on')); our database need it in yyyy-mm-dd format check the format of input before saving it to database

Comment: can u show us the Feed model

Comment: @arunkumar                                                                                        
class Feed extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'feed_news';
    use SoftDeletes;
    protected $softDelete = true;
    protected $dates = ['expires_on'];
}

Comment: @PrashantPrajapati       $res_news_date=explode("-",$date);
                $news_date=$res_news_date[2]."-".$res_news_date[1]."-".$res_news_date[0];
                $feed->date = $news_date;                                                              now im getting error as Undefined offset: 2

Comment: dd($date); and show the result, also read the first comment. u may not have fully valid date.

Comment: dd($date) is coming as "2018-16-02"